# How to validate input name array in Laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5.5

This is my input with `start_date[value]` :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess2" placeholder="" name="start_date[value]">
```

This is my validation:

```
$validator = Validator::make($data, [
        'type'        => 'required|string',
        'def_fields'  => 'required|array',
        'def_filters' => 'required|array',
        'start_date[value]'  => 'required|array',
        'end_date[value]'    => 'required|array',
    ],[
        'def_fields.required'  => 'Report field is required',
    ]);
```

So far I did this: 
start_date[value] 
start_date.* 
start_date.*.value

All of them seems to be not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misunderstood `start_date.value` to put rules against and apply rule as `array` it would be just `numeric` or `alpha_numeric` not `array` , so try like

```
start_date.value => "required|numeric",
```

Or with `array` or `min` 1 element in array

```
start_date => "required|array|min:1"
```

Comment: I also did this `'start_date.value'  => 'numeric|min:1',` works fine with me